# What is the best way to start beginner minecrafters learning commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I know a few Minecrafters that are not much farther from the title NOOB.
I have learned a lot about commands, but where do I even begin to teach them?  With the new 1.9 commands it will be even harder.  Is there a place or site that will let me introduce them to commands in a way they will understand?

Comment: Start simple, work your way up from there really. Maybe try simple summoning, with special effects etc. But as a question, this is likely going to be closed, as this is really up to opinion.

Comment: You may be right, but this is a serious problem for any new players and this question might not only benefit me so I can help, but other who are starting off.

Comment: That's fair, and I do agree, but I would really say that this isn't the right place to ask for that kind of thing. As is defined in the [help centre](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it is off-topic to ask for recommendations, for any reason, as it will just build up too much chatter.

Comment: You might be better off in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Well, if it gets closed it gets closed, I agree with you, but I'll let it sit for a while just to see what happens.  Cool?

Comment: No worries. In the meantime, try chat as I suggested. They're much more open to discussion there (hence why it's called chat!)

Comment: I think YouTube user largon1211 would be a good start also. He has a PhD in. Computer science and had a series on commands already about 1.9 update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiki page on commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) should definitely help, for starters. Beyond that, I'd say link them to Sethbling's or Etho's videos for command block usage.